# Android laggs when more than 1 sprite is present

Tags: android, performance, sprite, collision

I have a "simple" shooting game where I have a cannon in the center bottom that can shoot bitmaps to enemies (sprites).

Now I don't know if its the collision detection or the sprite itself but if I "spawn" more than one enemy it starts to lagg, after 15 its completly unplayable.

The only thing the sprite does is moves itself in a direction and changes the picture from a spritesheet and holds some variables, nothing much.

Collision detection is by going through an array of enemies and within that I go through a second array of bullets and for each enemy I check if a bullet has hit it by making a Rect by them both and check for overlaps.

Its a bit of code so I don't know if I should post some of it or not but you can ask me to post it if you need.

Comment: You can always time how much time you take per frame. If it's anything more than 20ms, you will probably see lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest that you will save yourself a lot of hassle and boilerplate code if you use a game library such as [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)? It's free, open-source, and will take care of sprites, collision detection, object pooling (to avoid GC kicking in and dragging your game to a grinding halt), input, and more. Also, if you use it right, you can develop your app on your PC with a rapid redeployment cycle (and I'm not talking about an android emulator) and push it to your phone less frequently. Believe it or not, I'm not affiliated with the creators in any way - I just think it's a pretty awesome library, it's amazing that it's free, and you will otherwise experience a lot of pain building everything from the ground up.

Of course if you really insist on doing it all from scratch, then yeah, you're going to have to provide some code.

Comment: I'd like to use something like that but then I'd have to learn the functions that come with it and redo my code, in the worst case remake it from scratch again -.- but.. I think I'll look into that.